# grep for getting the whole word based on specific character

Tags: shell, grep

I have a large text file with many columns and rows. I want to get the whole name in one of the columns (I don't know which column contain it) based on the part of string and also contents in the another column.

I tried something like this:

```
`cat file.txt | awk '$3=="A"; {grep -W "1/1"}'`.
```

Actually, I know just 1/1 from the whole name (whole name is **B=1/1** and exist in a column that I don't know). Although, I used -w and also tried -m, -e, none of them work well and instead of showing just B=1/1, the whole line corresponded to **$3=="A"** was printed. Could you please kindly help me out?

**Edit**: Sorry if it is unclear. below is a short example of my file:

```
A1  A1:67543    FRSYUZP=0/0 ERYOUTY=0/1 YUTREOZ=1/1 PAERUYT=0/0
A2  A2:98765    FRSYUZP=1/1 ERYOUTY=1/1 YUTREOZ=0/1 PAERUYT=0/0
A3  A3:89745    FRSYUZP=0/1 ERYOUTY=0/0 YUTREOZ=0/1 PAERUYT=0/0
```

It's a very large file with multiple columns that I don't show here. I would like to get the name=1/1 in each line if '$3=="A2:98765", so I used the above-mentioned command, but not work. Note that, I don't know the name (say FRSYUZP), when run the command, I just to get the name that are equal to =1/1.
Please kindly tell me your solution and let me know if you need further information.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
find . | xargs grep -sw '1/1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you better use desktop tools for your task. Since you need to inspect it, and lack the command line skills.

I suggest to convert your large text file to `csv` file and use speadsheet tool like `MS-Excel` or `LibreOffice-Calc` to handle it.

Here is a sample `awk` script that will transform your `input.txt` file to `csv` with `|` delimiter.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}1' input.txt > input.csv
```